# How can I download the Product Open Data database?

Tags: data-request, food, barcodes, okfn

I am wanting to find a worldwide open nutritional database.

I know there have been [questions about this](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/269) before and the answers all refer to [USDA's Agricultural Research Service](https://www.ars.usda.gov/) and [OKFN's Open Product Data](http://product.okfn.org/) sites.

The USDA one is very much restricted to US foods (I am in Australia) and, from what I can tell, doesn't include barcode info.

The OKFN database seems perfect, however, the site has been down since at least Dec '14.

Does anyone know where I could get a copy of the Product Open Data database?

I do not need an API, just the data will suffice.

**About the other post**:

I have seen a thread with almost the same question. That threat lead me to write this question as the accepted answer mentions the Product Open Data database, but, as I explained earlier, that website has been down. My question allowed me to find a way around this which is exactly what I explained I was looking for. So, no, not a duplicate.

Comment: Related: [What is the status of OKFN's Open Product Data project?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4748/70)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open API for nutritional information and/or food barcodes?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/269/open-api-for-nutritional-information-and-or-food-barcodes)

Comment: @JoeGermuska I have put in an explanation as to why not. That question actually introduced me to the Open Product Data database

Comment: @PatrickHoefler Thanks, I will keep an eye on it! Just so everyone knows, that post came after this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wayback Machine is always your best friend; Here's the data from 2014-02
http://web.archive.org/web/20140209011312/http://product-open-data.com/download/

[OPD Product Browser Web Repository](https://github.com/okfn/opd-product-browser-web)

There's also [open food facts](http://openfoodfacts.org/)

Comment: You, sir, are a legend! I completely forgot about the way back machine! Downloading now! This database should really start being maintained again, it's such an important database. Also, the openfoodfacts database only has ~300 Australian items.

Comment: i'm guessing they should be combined. interested?

Comment: Sounds like a challenge! I like challenges! I'm going to dive into this database and see how it's all set up and let you know. How would I get an email to you rather than chatting on here?

Comment: Is it already on github?

Comment: good catch @Suzana! I didn't have to make one, OKFN already has it. I edited the answer to reflect that. Thanks again!