# What is the status of OKFN's Open Product Data project?

Tags: products, okfn

**[Open Product Data](http://product.okfn.org/)** (also known as ***Product Open Data***) is a project run by [OKFN](https://okfn.org/). Its main goal is to build a public database of product data. There are already several [questions](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4742/70) [and](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/274/70) [answers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/734/70) related to this project here on Open Data Stack Exchange. However, the [main website](http://product-open-data.com/) has been dead for some months now, and the [official mailing list](https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/product/) is deserted.

What is the current status of this projects? Are there any plans or ongoing initiatives to revive it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We're actually looking for a new maintainer for the project.

The new version is running on Django and the source code is [here](https://github.com/okfn/labs-opd).

Answer (score 3):

For now the best place to check in on the status of the project is here:

http://discuss.okfn.org/t/can-we-resurrect-product-open-data-com/173

Currently there are some volunteers trying to get the site and databases up and running again.