# google nutritional info database

Tags: data-request

I wanted to make a talk-to app with a lot of info about foods,

do you know how can I get access to all the google nutritional info on foods and vegetables?

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/269/open-api-for-nutritional-information-and-or-food-barcodes

Answer (score 1):

Based on a few sample requests I made to Google that resulted in a Knowledge Graph answer like the ones you mentioned, it appears Google is using the USDA National Nutrient Database which you can browse for yourself at http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search

There is a REST API at http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/doc/index

I would also suggest you look into Nutritionix at https://www.nutritionix.com/api which includes this data from the USDA and much much more!