# API for localized nutrition and food data

Tags: data-request, api, food, translation

For a current project I am looking for an API (or 'offline' CSV like format) which contains names and nutrition (kilokalories, protein, vitamins, etc.) of food and ingredients.

What I found so far:

- the food API of the USDA: https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/doc/
- the CSV export of the Federal Agency of Switzerland for food: naehrwertdaten.ch (sorry - I don't have enough reputation to post more links)
- resolve EAN 13 code to products: http://www.product-open-data.com/
- a very similar discussion: [Open API for nutritional information and/or food barcodes?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/269/open-api-for-nutritional-information-and-or-food-barcodes)

Also there are some commercial APIs for resolving products to nutritions.
But what they are all lacking is multi-language support.

My Use Case are e.g.

1. User searches for "basmati rice" -> gets a response which list all the nutritions of basmati rice.
2. User searches for "Erdbeeren" (German for strawberries) -> gets a response which listing nutritions for strawberries.
3. User searches for "farine complète" (French for wholemeal flour) -> gets a response listing nutritions for wholemeal flour.

Just as a example. It is of course okay to first see a list of results and choose between e.g. different brands or variants.

Comment: Is this answer useful for you? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12959/1511 (also, perhaps your question is duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

You might have found that commercial one already and it is not multi-lingual but would cover all your use cases (you would have to translate your ingredient names to English using Google Translate though)

https://spoonacular.com/food-api