# API/Dataset Containing Nutritional and Physical Activity data?

Tags: data-request

Im trying to find an API or dataset which contains both - the dietary information for example the number of calories aswell as a deeper breakdown into carbs, fats, proteins etc and also data on the persons physical activity/exercise so for example stuff like type of activity, calories burned, duration etc.

There seems to be datasets on just Nutrition or just Physical activity, but not both for some reason. I can work around 2 different data sets but ideally I would prefer if they were both in one, is anyone aware of any?

Comment: Have you looked at [this thread](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10767/api-for-localized-nutrition-and-food-data)? ... I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly. Dietary needs given age, gender, health status, level of activity? Or, 1) dietary composition of foods, and 2) energy requirements by activity.

Comment: @Simon, Sorry yeah what I wrote was kind of ambiguous. Essentially what you said first, so Dietary intake of a person given their age, gender, and level of activity ideally it would contain a diet breakdown aswell as some detail about the activities the person does, but this is wishful thinking.

Comment: Ok. That is a tough one. Even for age and gender you may have to get estimates from the literature (i.e. no ready made csv for you). Let us know if you find/create something ...

Comment: @Simon Managed to find something, a National Diet and Nutrition Survey on the UK data service website, https://discover.ukdataservice.ac.uk/series/?sn=2000033#access. It contains data on users' dietary and physical activity information. You will need to register to use it though and its in a pspp .sav format but you can use R to convert .sav to .csv and go from there if you're looking to import to mongodb for example.

Comment: Nice work! I’ll sign up and have a look.